# How do I store a record in two tables with ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Let's say I have a schema

```
schema "posts"
  field ...
  field :post_id (UUID4)
  field :revision_id (UUID4)
end
```

On commit, I want to insert two copies of this data into two tables:

- UPSERT `table(:posts)` on `:post_id`, with `:post_id` as primary
- INSERT `table(:revisions)` on `:revision_id` as primary

Here's my code for inserting the two records:

```
  Multi.new()
  |> Multi.insert(:revisions, post)
  |> Multi.insert(:posts, post, on_conflict: :nothing)
  |> Repo.transaction()
```

My schema is defined on `Post`.

Currently it seems to try to insert the record twice on the same table (posts) and ignores the revisions table.

How can I force it to write to two separate tables?

Comment: as you can see when you define the schema, the "posts" is the table name, you have to create a new schema if you want to insert in a different table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Ecto.Multi

Here is a "textbook" example of using `Ecto.Multi` to create 2 related records: a `User` record and an `Email` record (this assumes a 1-to-many relationship between users and emails):

```
alias Ecto.Multi

Multi.new()
|> Multi.insert(:user, User.changeset(%User{}, user_params) end)
|> Multi.insert(:email, fn %{user: %User{id: user_id}} ->
  Email.changeset(%Email{user_id: user_id}, email_params)
end)
|> Repo.transaction()
```

For your case, you would need to adapt the models to "posts" and "revisions", and you would need to adapt the query(ies) to have an "upsert" functionality.  Make sure you are capturing the necessary data from the first table and passing it to the second so they can be properly associated in the database.

### Using Repo.transaction

I find that `Repo.transaction/1` is more readable and more flexible (you can even use it while operating against external events such an API calls etc).  An outline of using a transaction here would look something like this:

```
  def save_with_revision(params) do
    Repo.transaction fn ->
      with {:ok, revision} <- insert_revision(params) do
           {:ok, post} <- params |> Map.put(:revision_id, revision.id) |> upsert_post()
      do
        {:ok, post}
      else
        {:error, e} -> Repo.rollback(e)
      end
    end
  end
  
  defp insert_revision(params) do
    # ...
    {:ok, revision}
  end

  defp upsert_post(params) do
    # ...
    {:ok, post}
  end
```

You would need to implement functions to insert the revision and upsert the post, and I am assuming here that your `revisions` table is uses an `id` field as its primary key, but this outline should serve as a useful guide.  The important thing is that if either operation fails, execution is routed to `Repo.rollback/1`: the rows go in together successfully or not at all.

Comment: This was exactly the right answer. I did have to separate out and create separate models, but at least everything is easy to understand. Thanks so much for your help!